# HTML - How to link up a .JAR file

Tags: java, html, hyperlink, jar, download

When I try to link up a jar file to my website, and the user tries to download it, the file downloads as a `.ZIP` file instead of a `.JAR`.
Is there a way to fix this?

Note: I am using webs.com as my website server.

Comment: jar file is a zip file, no way to change that

Comment: @MatthewGilliard jar is also an archive but not the same as a zip file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What server are you using to serve the file?  The configured MIME type is probably not configured properly for `*.jar` files.  Ideally, it should be set to `application/java-archive`.

I would guess that currently, it is set to `application/zip` - or is being auto-detected as such based on the content of the JAR file - which is a derivative of a ZIP file and would be detected as a ZIP file.

Comment: The only COMPLETELY free thing I found is webs.com. Is there a better one that could do this?

Comment: If this is an open source library, consider hosting it on something like http://code.google.com, http://sourceforge.net, or  http://java.net.

Comment: For example, github, sourceforge, code.google.com, bitbucket, etc

Comment: Now, do these servers solve my issues? I would also really like a server that would support (meaning it can read) `.PHP` files. =P

Comment: Most of these hosting solutions will at least be smart enough to host files with the proper MIME types.